# Javascript dynamic requiring image

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create an dynamic backgroundImage based on some field value but I am not able to: Here is the error

```
Error: Cannot find module '../../assets/images/image1.jpg'
```

Method to generate the URL:

```
const getImageUrl = (index) =>
    `../../assets/images/image{index + 1}.jpg`;
```

Usage:

```
<div
          className="intro-section"
          style={{
            backgroundImage: `url(${require(getImageUrl(index))}`,
            backgroundSize: "cover",
            backgroundRepeat: "no-repeat",
            backgroundPosition: "center",
          }}
          onClick={() => navigateToAboutPage()}
        >
```

However, sending the string hardcoded works:

```
<div
              className="intro-section"
              style={{
                backgroundImage: '../../assets/images/image1.jpg',
                backgroundSize: "cover",
                backgroundRepeat: "no-repeat",
                backgroundPosition: "center",
              }}
              onClick={() => navigateToAboutPage()}
            >
```

Here is the sandbox:

https://codesandbox.io/s/optimistic-sanderson-hpvbf?file=/src/App.js

Comment: when you ask a question, you will get more complete answers if you post a working snippet that shows the problem you are having

Comment: Why are you using `require`. You could just write `url(${getImageUrl(index)})`.

Comment: Check my edit. I put the link of a sandbox

Comment: @Angelo, Edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ciao, [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/goofy-mclean-rrt9x) working example based on your codesandbox.
Basically, you need to use `require` to get image like this:

```
const getImageUrl = () => {
   let id = 1;
   const imageUrl = require(`./assets/images/image${id}.jpg`);
   return `url(${imageUrl})`;
};
```

style becomes:

```
style={{
        backgroundImage: getImageUrl(),
        backgroundSize: "cover",
        backgroundRepeat: "no-repeat",
        backgroundPosition: "center",
      }}
```

Comment: Ciao, I updated my answer modifying your codesandbox. What do you think?

Comment: Thank you. This is what I was looking for !

Answer (score 1):

The error comes from using `require()` as it expects a javascript module. Unlike `import` you can not load images, stylesheets or other filetypes that way, as far as I know.

**Solution 1:**
You can update the image by setting the url in your styles:

```
backgroundImage: `url(${getImageUrl(index)})`
```

**Solution 2:**
Another method would be to utilize the fetch API.

```
fetch(getImageUrl(index))
  .then(response => response.blob())
  .then(images => {
      // handle image, update stylesheet
  })
```

Comment: When you move the folder assets from `src` to `public` it will be provided to the webserver, and then the file is accessible.

If you keep it to src you would have to set specific delivery to make the image available, e.g. using a web asset bundler or a server route.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**:

Normal Relative imports seems not to work with **JSX**. You will have to `require` or `import` the image file so **webpack** would know that this component needs that image, But Just make sure you put all the images inside the **src** folder since **relative imports** are not supported from outside the src folder if `create-react-app` is used.

The following snippet is working correctly on the sandbox the Author provided in the question:

```js
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import bgImg from "./assets/images/image1.jpg";
// OR this using require
// const bgImg = require("./assets/images/image1.jpg");

export default function App() {
  // No Need for this line anymore
  // const getImageUrl = () => `url(./assets/images/image1.jpg)`;
  return (
    <div
      className="App"
      style={{
        backgroundImage: `url(${bgImg})`,
        backgroundSize: "cover",
        backgroundRepeat: "no-repeat",
        backgroundPosition: "center"
      }}
    >
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox.</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: @Angelo, I have edited my answer, and your sandbox.